# How do I extract by key in an object, on a sibling?

Tags: json, jq

How can I use **jq** to qualify filters on just some key values and reshape a hierarchy?

#### this is the input, from an Ansible log:

(the log format was by setting env variable `ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=json`)

I want to associate the `name` with the `msg`, but only for host `192.169.1.170`.

```
{
    "plays": [
        {
            "tasks": [
                {
                    "hosts": {
                        "192.169.1.70": {
                            "msg": "inventory_hostname:192.169.1.70:"
                        },
                        "dontcare": {
                            "msg": "dont want to see this:"
                        }
                    },
                    "task": {
                        "name": "debug inventory_hostname"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "hosts": {
                        "192.169.1.70": {
                            "msg": "All items completed"
                        }
                    },
                    "task": {
                        "name": "install system-level components"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

#### desired output:

```
{
  "name": "debug inventory_hostname",
  "msg": "inventory_hostname:192.169.1.70:"
},
{
  "name": "install system-level components",
  "msg": "All items completed"
}
```

I can extract some data, but I can't nest the sibling host msg, and I can't limit my search to just my host of interest, `192.169.1.70`:

`jq '.plays[] | .tasks[] | .task,.hosts' ansible.json`

```
{
  "name": "debug inventory_hostname"
}
{
  "192.169.1.70": {
    "msg": "inventory_hostname:192.169.1.70:"
  },
  "dontcare": {
    "msg": "dont want to see this:"
  }
}
{
  "name": "install system-level components"
}
{
  "192.169.1.70": {
    "msg": "All items completed"
  }
}
```

Whenever I try something to qualify the hosts key I want, `.hosts["192.169.1.170"]` or `.hosts.192.169.1.170` or `.hosts{"192.169.1.170"}`, `.hosts("192.169.1.170")`, I get either `null` or compile errors.  Most of the sample jq code concerns filtering arrays, not accessing hashmaps/dictionaries.

And, how would I grab the sibling data for the name and bring in the same object, as above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for `select` and addition operator (`+`).

```
.plays[].tasks[]
| select(.hosts | has("192.169.1.70"))
| .task + .hosts."192.169.1.70"
```

[REPL demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Ym6NF5gwFh)

Comment: Nice.  I was trying to break it down and  `jq '.plays[].tasks[]| .task + .hosts."192.169.1.70"'` seems to do get it done.  Is the `select has` unnecessary or does my data just happen to not need it in this particular instance?  And I take note of both the `+` and `.<keyvalue>` syntax.  and the online tester.  You're a prince, txs!  What are the jq-specific terms used to refer to `+` and the .-based filtering?  Just so that I know where to search the doc in the future?

Comment: If your data might contain othe IPs, select-has is necessary, otherwise not. `+` is basic addition, .key is  called *object-identifier index* in the manual